# Jruby Rails standalone war file ClassNotFoundException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, war

I am experienced ROR developer, but new to JRuby.
I am trying to create Rails application in Jruby and then making an executable WAR file using Warbler.

```
$warble executable war
```

It created a WAR file but when I tried to run it by

```
$java -jar myapp.war
```

It just throw up this error.

```
error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: winstone.Launcher
```

My on Ubuntu with RVM using JRuby 1.6.8, am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Warbler downloads this dependency for you when executing `warble executable war`, so something must have gone wrong during that phase.  This could potentially be a warbler bug, what version are you using?

Here are some leads:

- Is the winstone jar downloaded under `~/.m2/repository/org/jenkins-ci/winstone`?
- Is the webserver properly packaged in your war?

  `jar tvf your.war | grep webserver.jar`
- Try a different server by editing the warbler config in `config/warble.rb` and adding:

  `config.server = 'jetty'`

  (if you have no config yet, run `warble config`; this creates `config/warble.rb`)
- Try uninstalling the `warbler` gem, and reinstalling it.